# SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments always returns false

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm creating my second app with In App Purchase. Everything went great with the first app and it's up in the app store, however with the second app when I call [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments] I'm always getting a result of false. I've done the same steps between app 1 and 2. Can anyone point out other things I need to check?

thanks

Comment: Are you checking on the simulator or the device? Assuming you are talking about the Sandbox? Last time I tried to use in-app purchases we had all sorts of other problems as well.

Comment: Yes using the sandbox on device, in fact both apps are on the same device. The first app is functioning correctly.

Comment: Are you testing with a test user account ? or a real account ?

Comment: I have signed out of my real iTunes account and have tried it being signed out and being signed in to my test account.

Comment: I just spent 30 minutes trying to figure this out and it turns out I was checking for true instead of false. Pro-tip: always check the easy, obvious things first

Answer (score 20):

Check that in-app purchases are allowed in Settings->General->Restrictions.
This is one reason that SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments will return false.

EDIT for 2020: this is now located in Settings->Screen Time->Content & Privacy Restrictions.